# Aggregate Fishnet's Cells into 10 cells by 10 cells grid

Tags: raster, r, vector-grid

How can I generate an ID variable taking a different value for each 10 cells by 10 cells group in a raster?

Below is my code, built from [this example](https://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-create-grid-and-intersect-it.html).

In this example, each cell get an id (i.e., the cell's row number). I would like to group each 10 cells by 10 cells group into one bigger group. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
#Download brazil shapefile
http://www.mediafire.com/download/8mm53zrop54x1by/shape_brazil_post.rar

# Load our shapefile. Just choose the ".shp" file inside the folder you downloaded.
dryland <- readOGR(choose.files(), "dryland") 

grid <- raster(extent(dryland))
res(grid) <- 0.1 # Approximately 11 km (110.57*0.1)
proj4string(grid)<-proj4string(dryland)

gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(dryland) 

grid <- raster::intersect(gBuffer(dryland, width=1.1), gridpolygon)


grid@data <- grid@data %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

Comment: Can you make a fully reproducible example maybe using sample data (polygon regions) from the `sf` package? Then we're all on the same page with what you expect in terms of outputs.

Comment: I added the shapefile download.

Comment: `dryland` is a polygon, so `gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(dryland) ` fails because it expects a raster. Please try and make your question code work when copy-pasted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for may be achieved by using matrices and repetitions, and then assigning those values to the raster you build by `extent`; the plot at the end shows both raster and polygons made from the grid.

**EDIT:**

The following code was updated with your shapefile, after Spacedman's comment I found it was my unzip utility not working and not a corrupted file:

```r
library(raster)
library(sf)

nc = read_sf("/home/pronatura/Downloads/dryland.shp")

grid_r = raster(extent(nc), nrow = 50, ncol = 20)
crs(grid_r) = crs(nc)

vec_grid = vector(mode = "list", length = 5)
grid_num = seq(1,10,2)
for(i in seq_along(grid_num)) { 
  vec_grid[[i]] =  matrix(rep(c(rep(grid_num[i], 10), rep(grid_num[i]+1,10)), 10), ncol = 20, byrow = T)
}

values(grid_r) = do.call(rbind, vec_grid)

pol_fishnet = rasterToPolygons(grid_r, dissolve = T)
plot(grid_r)
plot(pol_fishnet, add = T)
plot(dryland, add = T, col = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: the shapefile works for me - the URL actually goes to a hosting/download page, and then you need to click a link there to get a RAR archive which extracts the shapefile. If you try and open that URL directly in R it will be flagged as corrupted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried again with `unrar` instead of the file explorer utility for unzipping and could open the file.